QGIS Native Dissolve only merges polygons vertically
I have a raster which I'm trying to convert into polygons. I have managed to convert them into polygons as seen below. All these polygons only have a value of 1 attached to them.

Now I want to merge adjacent polygons and have less number of polygons. And I found out I have to use Dissolve tool to do that. But when I run Dissolve with above input, I get an output like this:

As seen, polygons have only merged vertically and I have no idea why. There's no extra setting in the algorithm for this as far as I can see.

Can anyone help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

do your polygons touch to the sides?

Presumably yes, I generate the polygons using "Raster pixels to polygons" tool. But let me know if I can validate that.

do a select all that touch one of them and see what it finds

can you hint me how I do that? I'm fairly new to all these.

Use select by location: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbylocation with one feature selected and run the tool with spatial predicate Touch and Selected features only checked.

You mighttry to create a (very small) buffer around your polygons and dissolve these.

When I run that with Touch predicate, it doesn't select any of them. If I use Intersect predicate, then it selects the one below and above it. Interesting. I've added a buffer of 0.000001, and it really worked. If any of you can put that as an answer, I can accept it.

Sometimes vectorizing a float raster can cause problems like yours. If all the values are 1 anyway you can change the data type to to int using translate then vectorize the output
